# Asynctask: retrieving contact pics from a device phonebook

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my app iam trying to retrieve the images of the phonebook contact images and display in a list.below is my code

```
public InputStream getContactPhoto(Context context, String profileId){
        try{
            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(profileId));
            return ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
        }catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long id) {
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);

        InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);

        if (input == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    }
```

its working but somehow it not smooth, so wanna implement getting images using asynctask
Any suggestion on how to implement using the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using, for example, an ImageView and want to load a picture (in this example, it retrieves an image from the SDCard), you could do this:

-Create a custom class that extends ImageView

```
public class SDImageView extends CacheableImageView {
    ...
}
```

-Create a method called `load()` (or whatever you want) with your needed parameters. In my case is the path of the image:

```
public final void loadImage(final String tpath) {
        if (tpath == null) {
            return;
        }

        SDLoadAsyncTask.load(this, tpath);
    }
```

-Create a class that extends AsyncTask and implement the operations you want to do in the `doInBackground` method

```
private static class SDLoadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

        final SDImageView view;
        final String path;

        private SDLoadAsyncTask(SDImageView view, String path) {
            this.view = view;
            this.path = path;
        }

        @Override
        protected final Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + path);
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Utils.logMsg("Exception for img " + path, e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                }
            }
            return bmp;

        @Override
        protected final void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            view.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
}
```